Best Practices for Handling I/O Operations in Threads with FastAPI and asyncio
I am creating a project using FastAPI. When the project starts, it creates a thread by running the following line:
threading.Thread(target=calc_kpi_thread_wrapper).start()
def calc_kpi_thread_wrapper() -> None:
    asyncio.run(calc_kpi_thread())

The thread reads from Redis and sends data to the client through a WebSocket using WebSocket from Starlette, which supports asyncio programming:
from starlette.websockets import WebSocket

I am wondering, when running the thread function in asynchronous mode, should I use run_in_threadpool from FastAPI for reading from Redis or for any other I/O-bound synchronous operations ? is there any significant difference in performance ?
@inject
async def calc_kpi_thread(redis: Redis = Provide["redis_pool"]) -> None:
    while True:
        # Calculate the threshold for the last 2 hours
        now = datetime.now()
        two_hours_ago = now - timedelta(hours=2)
        threshold_ms = int(two_hours_ago.timestamp() * 1000) 

        # Fetch entries from the last 2 hours
        entries = redis.xread(
            streams={redis_stream_channel_name:threshold_ms},
            block=0
        )
        # Prepare a list of responses to send via WebSocket
        response_list: list[dict] = []
        ...
        if response_list:
            await websocket.send_json(response_list)
        ...



does using async with threads impact performance ?

@Tom McLean run_in_executor runs functions, not coroutines.  This behavior is documented.  The function runs in another thread (by default), or in another Process (if you specify the use of a ProcessPoolExecutor).  The function will run in the executor without blocking the event loop - that's basically the whole point of run_in_executor.  You seem to be under some misapprehensions about threads and event loops.  Threads are very important when performing blocking I/O, and are frequently used under the hood by functions in asyncio.
